# Use a static readonly field in constructor C#

Tags: c#, constructor, static, field

Below is my class with a static readonly field :

```
public class Stats
{
    public static readonly int MinPoints = 900;
    public static readonly int MaxPoints = 1500;

    public int Points { get; }

    private Stats()
    {
    }

    public Stats(int points) : this()
    {
        if (points < Stats.MinPoints || points > Stats.MaxPoints)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        Points = points;
    }
}
```

When compiling, I don't have any errors. But when I try to instanciate a `Stats` object, I'm getting a `TypeInitializationException`. When replacing `PlayerStatistics.MaxPoints` in the constructor with its proper value, the code works.

Here is the error I get when unit testing the constructor :

```
Expected a <System.InvalidOperationException> to be thrown, but found <System.TypeInitializationException>: "
"System.TypeInitializationException with message "The type initializer for 'League.Domain.Player.Stats' threw an exception."
     at League.Domain.Player.Stats..ctor(Int32 points) in C:\dev\repos\League\League.Domain\Player\Stats.cs:line 24
     at League.Tests.StatsSpecs.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Create_stats_with_incorrect_points_should_throw_exception>b__0() in C:\dev\repos\League\League.Tests\StatsSpecs.cs:line 36
     at FluentAssertions.Specialized.ActionAssertions.InvokeSubject()
     at FluentAssertions.Specialized.DelegateAssertions`1.InvokeSubjectWithInterception()
.
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args)
   at FluentAssertions.Specialized.DelegateAssertions`1.Throw[TException](Exception exception, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at FluentAssertions.Specialized.DelegateAssertions`1.Throw[TException](String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at League.Tests.StatsSpecs.Create_stats_with_incorrect_points_should_throw_exception(Int32 points) in C:\dev\repos\League\League.Tests\StatsSpecs.cs:line 38
```

And here is my unit test, written with XUnit :

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(899)]
[InlineData(1501)]
public void Create_stats_with_incorrect_points_should_throw_exception(int points)
{
    Action action = () => new Stats(points);

    action.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>();
}
```

Is there a way to still use the static readonly field in the constructor ?

Comment: Side note: `public static const int MaxPoints = 1000;` is a better syntax (assign at compile time)

Comment: You're referring to `MaxPoinst` in `PlayerStatistics`, which is not the `MaxPoints` you declared in this `Stats` class. You may have a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Side note: `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(points));` - let's be specific

Comment: Most likely the `PlayerStatistics` class is having some problems in its static field initializers or constrcutor, but we cannot see that class. Or did you mean that the class in the question *is*  `PlayerStatistics`? Or perhaps you meant to write `Stats.MaxPoints` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I changed PlayerStatistics to Stats

Comment: The code as written now does not produce the given exception. Can you post a [mcve] so that we can reproduce it? There is no code in the static field initializers that can produce a type initialization exception so my guess is that you've simplified the code down to a point where it no longer exhibits the problem you're describing.

Comment: I created a unit test to test if the exception was thrown when passing incorrect values. And you're true, I tried to simplify the code, so I'm gonna edit the post with the good one and add the errors aswell.

Comment: The code in your question still does not produce a TypeInitializationException.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the solution...

I tried to simplify my code too much, and omitted to put a line in my class :

```
public class Stats
{
    // I didn't put this line of code, so it was working without it
    public static readonly Stats New = new Stats(1000);

    public static readonly int MinPoints = 900;
    public static readonly int MaxPoints = 1500;

    public int Points { get; }

    private Stats()
    {
    }

    public Stats(int points) : this()
    {
        if (points < Stats.MinPoints || points > Stats.MaxPoints)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        Points = points;
    }
}
```

So as mentioned Dmitry Bychenko, static readonly field are not assign at compile time. So if I were to put these lines before the line I ommited, like this :

```
public static readonly int MinPoints = 900;
public static readonly int MaxPoints = 1500;

public static readonly Stats New = new Stats(1000);
```

It would work fine.

And thanks to his comment, using const instead of a static readonly field make my code work, at any place I put these these two constants in my class.